# set cursor at the end of a substring in a contentediatable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here user enters some string and string contains `Mahi` as substring. I am trying to place cursor at the end of `Mahi` on click of button?

### .html

```
<div id="demo" contenteditable="true"></div>

<button id="btn" onclick="focusAtMen()"></button>
```

## js

```
// lets suppose user input is "Hi.......Mahi, .....?";
// here dots may be any characters

focusAtMen(){
var editor = document.getElementById("demo");
// set focus on `contentEditable div` and `place cursor at the end` of `Mahi` , thats a user Input.

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Range.setStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart) and [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to get the cursor caret position.  The setStart function takes a node and an offset as the start position within that node.

The code below handles the case when `Mari` is present in the text.  It also handles the case when `Mari` is not contained in the string and in this case it places the caret at the last character of the text.

```js
function focusAtMen() {
  var textToFind = 'Mahi';
  var editor = document.getElementById("demo");

  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  
  // get the index of the start of 'Mahi'
  var indexOfMahi = editor.innerText.lastIndexOf(textToFind);
  
  if (indexOfMahi > -1) {
      // if text contains Mari
      range.setStart(editor.childNodes[0], indexOfMahi + textToFind.length);
  } else if (editor.innerText.length > 0) {     
     // if text does not contain Mari set cursor to the end of the string 
     range.setStart(editor.childNodes[0], editor.innerText.length);
  } else {
     // there is no text
     range.setStart(editor, 0);
  }
  
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" contenteditable="true">some text Mahi and another Mahi included</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="focusAtMen()">Click</button>
```

Note that the above code is case sensitive, if you need this to work for `mari` and `Mari` it will need to be modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks haldo, can you suggest some solution when user enters duplicates 'Mahi' and then  how to handle it. indexOfMahi + 4, here 4 is 'Mahi' length? I have updated question. Thank you

Comment: @Mahi Your updated question is unclear.  I've updated answer using `lastIndexOf` which will place the cursor after the last occurrence of Mahi.  Yes, I use the length of Mahi (4) to position the cursor.

Comment: @Mahi please ask a new question and rollback your edit.  The edited question is now different to the one you originally asked and as such you should ask a new question.